# Changing mode of Date Picker

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker

I have my Date Picker as:

[image]

But how do I make it like below:

[image]

Comment: You could use UIDatePicker with 4 custom styled components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the **UIDatePickerMode** to **UIDatePickerModeCountdownTimer**.

for e.g

```
var pickerView = UIDatePicker()
pickerView.datePickerMode = .CountDownTimer
```

for more information you can see in [Apple Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDatePickerMode)